# Are game modes in Garry's Mod free?

Tags: garrys-mod

Do you have to pay for the gamemodes in Garry's Mod or are they free? I've looked up and not found anything and watched videos to try and find out but I did find a Steam page that some people say its free some say that you have to pay so are they free?

Answer (score 2):

All of the game modes in Garry's Mod are free. However, some servers or custom game modes may use assets from other Source games, such as Counter-Strike: Source, Team Fortress 2, or Half Life 2: Episode 2.

If you do not own these games or do not have them installed, any missing textures from those games will replaced by a pink checkerboard while missing models will display as a red ERROR.

[image: Red error text]

Answer (score 0):

Garry's Mod gamemodes are completely free, with an exception being those from random websites that try and sell you a hack with the gamemode.

They can be downloaded directly into your game from the [Steam Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=4000&requiredtags%5B%5D=Gamemode).

Comment: I'm saying you have to own games to get some modes

Comment: Not really. However some maps and gamemodes require another game like CS:S. if you don't you'll just see a big ERROR over things you don't have the textures for

Comment: That's what I'm saying anyway this has already mean answered